# C# Random Pair generation

Tags: c#, linq

Assume the possible outcome of a die thrown is one of {1,2,3,4,5,6}

When **two dice** are thrown **three times**, I want to collect random 
outcomes from two dice.

My implementation is

```
var q = from threeTimes in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
                    let set1 = new Random().Next(1, 6)
                    let set2 = new Random().Next(1, 6)
                    select new { s1 = set1, s2 = set2 };

            foreach (var v in q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Die1 :{0} Die2 :{1}", v.s1, v.s2);
            }
```

But most of the times I receive the same values for Die1 and Die2.

I mean

```
Die1: 5   Die2:  5

Die1: 2   Die2:  2

Die1: 2   Die2:  2
```

What correction do I need to make in order to get random pairs?

Comment: Singular: die or dice
Plural: dice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because you are creating two `Random` objects effectively instantaneously. By default, they are seeded using a time based value, most likely `Environment.TickCount`, though I haven't seen this confirmed.

Constructing one `Random` before your query will solve this, as will seeding the two objects separately:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var q = from threeTimes in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        let set1 = rnd.Next(1, 6)
        let set2 = rnd.Next(1, 6)
        select new { s1 = set1, s2 = set2 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Give your Random a seed (its other constructor) and keep using the same instance instead of newing one up every time.

Answer (score 2):

Create one Random() instance, then call .Next() on that:

```
Random random = new Random();
var q = from threeTimes in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
                    let set1 = random.Next(1, 6)
                    let set2 = random.Next(1, 6)
                    select new { s1 = set1, s2 = set2 };

            foreach (var v in q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dice1 :{0} Dice2 :{1}", v.s1, v.s2);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens in you run random.Next(); In between?

I think that two calls in the same second will retrieve the same value when using the constructor, in that way you are using it.
Try to create a instance of Random and use that one instead.

Random r = new Random();
let set1 = r.next(1,6);
let set2 = r.next(1,6);

Answer (score 0):

Bart de Smet has a pretty heavy duty [article](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/09/12/taming-your-sequence-s-side-effects-through-ienumerable-let.aspx) on this you might want to check.